# Memory allocation and core dump for pointers to structures in c

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, malloc

Sorry I'm new to memory allocation and structure (so most probably it's some silly thing I've missed). I've got the following code which is core dumping on Solaris. I'm not also sure how to add more elements later (should I realloc memory?)

```
 enum field_type
 {
        FLD_STRING, 
        FLD_SHORT
 };


 typedef struct {
    long        id;
    char        *name;
    field_type  type;
    void        *value;
 } myStruct_t ;

 typedef struct {
    long id;
    const char *name;
    field_type type;
    const char *descr;
 } myStructDef_t;

 myStructDef_t Alldef[] = 
 {
    {0, "FirstField", FLD_STRING, "First Field Of Structure"},
    {1, "SecondField", FLD_STRING, "Second Field Of Structure"},
    {-1}
 };


 int main()
 {
    myStruct_t *p_struct;
    char tmp[100] = {'\0'};
    long id = 0;

    if(NULL == (p_struct= structAlloc(1024)))
    {
        print("Failed allocating memory\n");
        return 0;
    }
    sprintf(tmp, "Test Adding value");
    addValueToStruct(p_struct, id, (void *)tmp);

 }

 myStruct_t *structAlloc(long size)
 {
    myStruct_t *tmp = (myStruct_t *) calloc(size, sizeof *tmp);
    if(NULL != tmp)
        tmp->id = -1;
    return tmp;
 }

 int addValueToStruct(myStruct_t *p_struct, long id, (void *)value)
 {
    myStruct_t *bkStruct = p_struct;
    myStructDef_t *def = NULL;

    if(-1 == getIdDefinition(def, id))
    {
        printf("Failed to find definition for id [%ld]", id);
        return -1;
    }

    // Core dumping on 1st line below
    bkStruct->id = def->id;
    sprintf(bkStruct->name, "%s", def->name);
    bkStruct->type = def->def->type;
    if(FLD_SHORT == bkStruct->type)
        memcpy(bkStruct->value, value, sizeof(*(short *)value));
    else if(FLD_STRING == bkStruct->type)
        memcpy(bkStruct->value, value, sizeof(*(char *)value));

    return 0;
 }

 int getIdDefinition(myStructDef_t *def, long id)
 {
    myStructDef_t *AllDefsTmp = Alldef;
    bool found = false;

    while( -1 != AllDefsTmp->id)
    {
        if(id == AllDefsTmp->id)
        {
            def = AllDefsTmp;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        AllDefsTmp ++;
    }

    if(!found)
        return -1;

    return 0;

 }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Your code doesn't compile - `malloc()` does not take two arguments, for example. There are several other compiler errors. But after fixing them, I can see what's wrong...

Comment: yeah, sorry it's just a very fast simplified copy of my original code, was trying calloc as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myStructDef_t *def = NULL;

if(-1 == getIdDefinition(def, id))
{
    printf("Failed to find definition for id [%ld]", id);
    return -1;
}

// Core dumping on 1st line below
bkStruct->id = def->id;
```

Calling `GetIdDefinition(def, id)` will fill in `def` within the that function, but won't change the value within the `addValueToStruct` function - you need a double pointer (in C) or reference (in C++), so that you can change the value of `def` itself. (Or you could of course just return the value you found, instead of `-1` or `0` return value).

Comment: Thanks :) seems to pass this line and def has the correct values, but it's core dumping on the second line now when trying to add the name. I printed the memory allocated and it's 4, doesn't sound right to me :/ any suggestions about that? should I realloc memory based on the size of each variable? thanks again

Comment: Well, I can't find anywhere that you allocate memory for `name` - it may be that you've cut that out of your example you've posted, or that's why it's not working to write to it...

Comment: doesn't malloc (or calloc in this case) allocate memory for the whole structure :$ sorry again new to this

Comment: `name` is a pointer. `malloc` only allocates the memory for the structure, not any of the pointers WITHIN the structure. You could of course use `char name[SOMETHING]` where SOMETHING is a suitable size, e.g. 16 or 20, instead of allocating a second memory block just for the name - which will take much more than 16 bytes.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, well SOMETHING isn't really of fixed length, it will depend on values parsed from a file. thanks for the explanation :) getting better at this :)

Comment: Yes, my point is that if you restrict it to a smallish size (e.g. 32 bytes), it will be more memory effective to have a fixed size char array than allocating a second lot of memory. Even at 64 bytes, it's probably worthwhile doing.